# Want to make sure I'm on the right track

Tags: c++

It's a stretch project and one of the pieces I'm stuck on. Overall, I'm going to use C++ OOP to write this project.

One of the objects would be as follows:

An automatically generated character string to identify the
reservation number. The string must be in the form NNLLNLLN,
where N is a number from 0 to 9, and L is a character from A
to Z.

I'm thinking pseudocode wise I could do the following:

Generate a random number, S1, convert to string
Generate a random number, S2, convert to string
Generate a random letter, S3
Generate a random letter, S4
Generate a random number, S5, convert to string
Generate a random letter, S6
Generate a random letter, S7
Generate a random number, S8, convert to string

then the result would be S1+....S8

My thought is don't try and be cute and come up with something fancy and waste time writing this program. It's simply the reservation number. Thoughts?

For those that want codes for each random letter:

```
char c;
int r;

srand (time(NULL));    // initialize the random number generator
for (i=0; i<1; i++)
{    r = rand() % 26;   // generate a random number
      c = 'a' + r;            // Convert to a character from a-z
      cout << c;
}
```

For those that wants codes for each random number:

```
{ 
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
    int random_integer; 
    for(int index=0; index<10; index++)
   { 
    random_integer = (rand()%9)+1; 
    cout << random_integer << endl; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? If it is doing what you are expecting it to do, then yeah your approach is correct.

Comment: Might need to ensure that all the reservation code are unique though. However, the odds of having the same 2 reservation code being the same seems to be low.

Comment: You can simplify what you are thinking a little. Make an 8 character `std::string` and set the characters in it as you figure them out. Save you from having to put the `string` together bit by bit.

Comment: Numbers can be turned into a digit character by adding the number to the value of character '0'.

Comment: @user4581301 great suggestion! I ended up generating the random letter or number and using push_back to append it to the result string. Thanks much!